# I've failed to show lists of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, wifi-direct

I am building my first android app using WiFi Direct to transfer
text, image, and media files to peers.I am using a RecyclerView 
and a Fragment. I hope to show peers's list on a framelayout 
(a simple textview) and then click the views to form a group
to send files. I am stuck at the first stage of making the list shown
on the parent's view. I would appreciate your help on what I did wrong.
I am just a beginner. Any advice or resources would be welcome even besides the pending problem. The followings are three classes and two xmls I've made fumbling around many sources and Android Developer's guide.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static String TAG="test";
IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
WifiP2pManager mManager;
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
public static boolean setIsWifiP2pEnable;
    Button open, connect, file, image, media;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        open = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wifi_open);
        connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        file = (Button) findViewById(R.id.file);
        image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        media = (Button) findViewById(R.id.media);


        open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();


        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);


        mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);


        checkWiFi();


        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.d (TAG, "search start");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                        Log.d (TAG, "search failed");                   
                    }
                });
            }
        });



        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new DeviceFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            Log.d (TAG, "fragment_activated");
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume () {
        super.onResume();
        mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause () {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    public void checkWiFi(){
        if(setIsWifiP2pEnable==true){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WiFi Direct connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Open WiFi Direct in settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

    public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static WifiP2pManager mManager;
    public static WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
    private MainActivity mActivity;
    public static List<WifiP2pDevice> peers = new ArrayList<>();

    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, WifiP2pManager.Channel channel,
                                       MainActivity activity) {
        super();
        this.mManager = manager;
        this.mChannel = channel;
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();


        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(mManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
            if (state==mManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED){
                Log.d (MainActivity.TAG, "WiFi_enabled");
                mActivity.setIsWifiP2pEnable=true;
                mActivity.checkWiFi();
            } else {
                Log.d (MainActivity.TAG, "WiFi_failed");
                mActivity.setIsWifiP2pEnable=false;
                mActivity.checkWiFi();
            }

        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            if (mManager != null) mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {
                    Log.d (MainActivity.TAG, "peers_found");
                    peers.clear();
                    peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());

                    if(peers.size() ==0){
                        Log.d (MainActivity.TAG, "No_Peers_found");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });

        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to new connection or disconnections

            if (mManager==null) {
                return;
            }

            NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

            if (networkInfo.isConnected()){
                mManager.requestConnectionInfo(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo info) {                 
                        InetAddress groupOwnerAddress = info.groupOwnerAddress;
                        String s=groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress();

                        if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {
                        } else if (info.groupFormed) {
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        }
    }
}

    public class DeviceFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mDeviceRecyclerView;
    private DeviceAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<WifiP2pDevice> mDevices;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_device_list, container,false);

        mDeviceRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.device_recycler_view);
        mDeviceRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        updateUI();

        return view;
    }

    private void updateUI(){

        mDevices = WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.peers;
        mAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(mDevices);
        mDeviceRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        Log.d (MainActivity.TAG, "adapter_connected");
    }

    private class DeviceHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView mTitleTextView;

        public DeviceHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView;
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Item_Click_try");
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Click Succeeded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            int i =  (int) v.getTag();
            WifiP2pDevice device = mDevices.get(i);

            WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
            config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
            config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;


           WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.mManager.connect(WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.d (MainActivity.TAG, "Click_Success!!");

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    Log.d (MainActivity.TAG, "Click_Failed!!");
                }
            });
        }
    }


    private class DeviceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DeviceHolder>{
        private List<WifiP2pDevice> Devices;

        public DeviceAdapter(List<WifiP2pDevice> devices){
            Devices=devices;
            Log.d (MainActivity.TAG, "device_list");
        }

        @Override
        public DeviceHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            View view=layoutInflater
                    .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            Log.d (MainActivity.TAG, "simple_list");
            return new DeviceHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(DeviceHolder holder, int position) {
            WifiP2pDevice device = Devices.get(position);
            holder.mTitleTextView.setTag(position);
            holder.mTitleTextView.setText(device.deviceName);
            Log.d (MainActivity.TAG, "Device_bound");
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mDevices.size();
        }
    }
}

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.moon.android.wifidirectproject_moon.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/wifi_open"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="WiFi_Direct" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/connect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Connect" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/file"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="file" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="gallery" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/media"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="media" />

    </LinearLayout>


The Other Layout:

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/device_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: question is very vague. are you with an error or no output. No debugging details in your question.

Comment: Actually, no output was shown. But strangely enough, while writing the post, I found that a peer device is shown as I wanted (The Fragment code worked!). Thrilled, I tried to refresh but nothing is shown again. However, after turned off by energy-saving mode (after some time has passed), the code worked again. I checked the LogCat and found that the phone started to bind the view by itself (showing logs of DeviceFragment class - simple_list, Item_Click_try, Device_bound in a row). I suspect that something is wrong in Adapter class or ArrayList. But really not sure.

Comment: Does not function. Only the following logcat: fragment_activated>>device_list>>adapter_connected>>search start(after pressing "connect buttion">>WiFi_enabled>>peers_found. When it functions(only once for a phone), the logcat shows: simple_list>>Item_Click_try>>Device_bound.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have made some (not complete) progress on my question. I suspected that the ArrayList information is not properly delivered to my fragment class. So I wrote the following code in OnCreate method in MainActivity:

```
DeviceFragment df = new DeviceFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("bundle",WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.peers);
df.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

if (fragment == null) {
    fragment = df;
    fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .commit();
    Log.d (TAG, "fragment_activated");
}
```

I put the following code in my fragment class:

```
   mDevices = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("bundle");
```

and revised Adapter class as follows:

```
public DeviceAdapter(List<WifiP2pDevice> devices){
    Devices=devices;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d (MainActivity.TAG, "device_list");
}
```

It worked. But I met with one more problem. The textviews on screen are refreshed only when I turned off and on again (not powered on/off). So, I want to make a "refresh button" in MainActivity so that I can refresh the list like when turning on/off. But I have no idea **how I can refresh the RecyclerView's fragment in MainActivity**. I think I should work on fragmentManager and transaction. Could anybody help me deal with this issue?